# Is this the right way to find the size and the angle with respect to the given z-axis for the nitrogen atoms spin?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

A nitrogen atom has in its ground state a spin with a quantum number s=3/2:
. Determine the possible results of measurement of the size and the angle
with respect to the given z-axis for the nitrogen atoms spin!

**Solution**

A nitrogen atom in its ground state has a spin with a quantum number $s = 3/2$. The magnitude of the spin angular momentum (|s|) can be calculated as follows:

\begin{equation}
|s| = \sqrt{s(s+1)} = \sqrt{3/2 * (3/2 + 1)} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2} * \frac{5}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{15}{4}} = \sqrt{\frac{15}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}
\end{equation}

The possible results of measurement for the spin angular momentum projection along a given $z$-axis ($m_z$) are: $m_z = -3/2, -1/2, 1/2,$ and $3/2$.

The corresponding angles ($\theta$) with respect to the $z$-axis can be calculated as follows:

\begin{equation}
\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{m_z}{|s|}\right)
\end{equation}

So for each possible value of $m_z$, the corresponding angle $\theta$ can be found using the above expression:
\begin{align*}
m_z &= -3/2 &\rightarrow &\quad \theta &= \cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{3/2}{\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}}\right) \\
m_z &= -1/2 &\rightarrow &\quad \theta &= \cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{1/2}{\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}}\right) \\
m_z &= 1/2 &\rightarrow &\quad \theta &= \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1/2}{\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}}\right) \\
m_z &= 3/2 &\rightarrow &\quad \theta &= \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3/2}{\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}}\right)
\end{align*}

Note: The angles $\theta$ are unique up to $360^\circ$, so they can take on multiple values depending on the reference frame.

Comment: While not relevant to the geometrical problem, should probably be emphasized that these angles ultimately don't have a physical meaning: one really can't adopt the image of a spin-3/2 particle as rotating in space. See the answers over at PSE [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/189799/55641) for more discussion. (This is a criticism of this kind of problem, to be clear, not of your own work.)

Comment: That said: Yes, your work here appears to be entirely correct. (It's just that there's in fact no such measurement that would yield this angle.)

Comment: Thank you very much for checking my answer @Semiclassical I will take a look at the link u gave

Comment: These are strictly notional visualization imagery angles in the [vector model of angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_coupling#/media/File:Vector_model_of_orbital_angular_momentum.svg).